# Redirect users from other websites based on browser language

Tags: php, redirect

I want to do this:

```
if (user from other website, like google, or input our website URL directly in the browser)
{
//redirect according to browser languge
        if (!preg_match('/en-US/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
        {
        wp_redirect("http://cn.gearor.com");
    }
}
```

I don't know how to write the first if statement, I don't know how to get the from URL and how to check it's my website or other websites. If it's my website, do nothing, if it's not my website, check if the browser is English, if not, redirect to http://cn.gearor.com

Comment: As others have mentioned, the accept header is the right place to get this information, not the user agent and *especially* not geolocation. It's worth noting that there are English locales other than US, so you might want to match en-.. instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like:

```
if (!preg_match('%your_domain.tld%i', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
    if (!preg_match('/en-us/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']))
        // .. do your stuff here.
}
```

I changed your language check to use HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, and to also not be case sensitive (Opera uses en-US where Firefox and IE use en-us in my tests).

You could also consider using `/^en-us/i` if you are checking for the DEFAULT language. The language strings can contain multiple languages, comma delimited.

Comment: I tried to test your code using google to entry my website, it's working. Thanks jasonbar.

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is the full URL that led to the page that checks it. It's not guaranteed to be set, though it's the only way to know what you're looking for.

Also, you may want to check `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` for the language of the user.

Here is the [full reference to the `$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) superglobal array. You should check the keys, especially those starting with `HTTP_`.